# Maximum range occupied by nonoverlapping intervals in python

Tags: python, intervals

Given a list of intervals, I would like to identify the non-overlapping subset of that list that occupies the largest total integer range.  For example, if the ranges are:

```
listy = [[0,10],[11,15],[11,12],[20,30]]
```

then the correct subset of intervals would be [0,10], [11,15] and [20,30], making the max non-overlapping total range equal to (10 + 4 + 10) = 34.

The approaches I keep coming up with seem to involve variations on just brute forcing through all subsets - there has to be a better way!

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post your best attempt and some specific questions about how to make it better. Right now, there's really nothing for people to work with, unless they feel like writing the entire program for you. You may also want to read about [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), since your question reminds me of some problems that are solved most efficiently with dynamic programming.

Comment: If `listy` is really this small, just brute force over the power set. If it's bigger… then is a close and/or likely answer useful to you, or not? If not, you're probably hosed, as Simeon Visser explains.

Comment: What does, e.g., [2, 4] represent, exactly?  Inclusive on both ends (2, 3 and 4)?  Inclusive on the left and exclusive on the right (2 and 3)?  Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There most likely isn't a better way. You're trying to solve various instances of the (max) subset sum problem which is NP-complete. Hence there most likely isn't an efficient algorithm for your problem.